# Postfix: routing applyed to wrong recipient when using check_recipient_mx_access

Tags: postfix

i am using check_recipient_mx_access so I can route all office365 hosted or google hosted domains to a special email gateway [because SPF, DMARC, so on].

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = ..., check_recipient_mx_access hash:/etc/postfix/mx_access,...
```

in /etc/postfix/mxaccess

```
 .protection.outlook.com FILTER smtp:[IP.AD.DR.ESS]
 .google.com FILTER smtp:[IP.AD.DR.ESS]
```

this work well for every single recipient, but sometimes fail when there is multiple recipient.

for example sender@mydom send to dest1@hotmail AND dest2@mydom2
then the dest2@mydom2 is relayed to [IP.AD.DR.ESS] which is wrong.

That is ok for the first recipient because its MX resolve something.protection.outlook.com but not the second one, because mydom2 has a special routing in transport_maps which is not used in that case and because its MX do NOT resolve in something that match mxaccess table.

[routing is OK if there is only dest2@mydom2 as recipient ]

[routing is OK if there is multiple @mydom2 @mydom3 dest, without matching mxaccess ]

NB:this is postfix 3.3.0 on ubuntu.

```
postconf -M
smtp       inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
pickup     fifo  n       -       -       60      1       pickup
cleanup    unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
qmgr       fifo  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr     unix  -       -       -       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite    unix  -       -       -       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
defer      unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
trace      unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
verify     unix  -       -       -       -       1       verify
flush      unix  n       -       -       1000?   0       flush
proxymap   unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
smtp       unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
relay      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp -o fallback_relay=
showq      unix  n       -       -       -       -       showq
error      unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
discard    unix  -       -       -       -       -       discard
local      unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual    unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp       unix  -       -       -       -       -       lmtp
anvil      unix  -       -       -       -       1       anvil
scache     unix  -       -       -       -       1       scache
maildrop   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
uucp       unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
ifmail     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix - n       n       -       2       pipe flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py ${nexthop} ${user}
retry      unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
policyd-spf unix -       n       n       -       0       spawn user=policyd-spf argv=/usr/sbin/postfix-policyd-spf-perl


~# postconf -n
alias_database = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
command_directory = /usr/sbin
compatibility_level = 2
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command = PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin xxgdb $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
inet_interfaces = all
local_recipient_maps =
mail_owner = postfix
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
message_size_limit = 20480000
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, penty.of.domains.tld
mynetworks = 172.16.0.0/16, 192.168.10.0/24, 127.0.0.0/8, 10.0.0.0/24
myorigin = /etc/mailname
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-1.1.12/README_FILES
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-1.1.12/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_invalid_hostname, check_recipient_mx_access hash:/etc/postfix/mxaccess, permit_mynetworks, reject_non_fqdn_recipient, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_non_fqdn_sender, check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/recipientaccess, reject_unauth_pipelining, reject_unauth_destination, reject_unverified_recipient, check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/senderaccess, reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_rbl_client sbl.spamhaus.org, reject_rbl_client psbl.surriel.com, reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net, reject_rbl_client dnsbl-3.uceprotect.net, check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:60000, check_policy_service unix:private/policyd-spf, permit
smtpd_relay_restrictions = reject_invalid_hostname, reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_non_fqdn_recipient, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, permit_mynetworks, reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unauth_pipelining, reject_unauth_destination, check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/recipientaccess, reject_unverified_recipient, check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/senderaccess, reject_rbl_client sbl.spamhaus.org, reject_rbl_client psbl.surriel.com, reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net, reject_rbl_client dnsbl-3.uceprotect.net, check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:60000, check_policy_service unix:private/policyd-spf, permit
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_ciphers = high
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
virtual_alias_domains = XXXXXXXXXX
virtual_alias_maps = regexp:/etc/postfix/virtual_re
```

Comment: only some of my MX are fully compliant to send email to google or office365. So I want to use these and not use the non-compliant one.

Comment: added & edit postconf -M & -n

Comment: I'm also trying to solve this for a similar reason. It seems like any matching RCPT TO makes the rule match, and the relay is changed for the whole delivery. I'd tried setting `smtp_destination_recipient_limit=1` to try to split the delivery up (which used to be e.g. qmail's default), but it doesn't seem to result in the routing I want.

Answer (score 2):

> That is ok for the first recipient because its MX resolve
> something.protection.outlook.com but not the second one, because
> mydom2 has a special routing in transport_maps which is not used in
> that case and because its MX do NOT resolve in something that match
> mxaccess table.

i found this text:

- If a message triggers more than one filter action, only the last one
  takes effect.
- The same content filter is applied to all the recipients of a given
  message.

at: http://www.postfix.org/FILTER_README.html#dynamic_filter